# Cosa vuol dire l'espressione "quando mai no"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Totooò! che si dice?» 
>       «Malacque! Malacque!» 
>       **Quando mai no**. Sta rovistando sotto la prua, sempre seduto così. E poi, vivo brilla nella mano, un sarago. «Tutta la notte a traìna, fuori Pietra Salata, fino a Nìsida, con l’umidità dentro le ossa, pe’ ’sto coso che se ci fai trecento lire è già assai!» Sempre la stessa canzone, e sbatte il sarago nella barca. Però, veramente, che vita fanno.

Per si è d'aiuto, il romanzo è ambientato a Napoli.

Tentando di capire il significato della frase "quando mai no" che appare in questo brano, ho ricercato alla voce "quando" di alcuni dizionari. Sul [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/Q/quando.html) ho trovato

> Quando mai!, nient'affatto, certamente no, sicuramente no: *noi dimenticarti? q. mai!*

Il significato di "quando mai no" sarebbe lo stesso? O forse l'aggiunta di "no" indica il contrario e il significato nel passo citato sarebbe "certamente", "come no"?

È la prima volta che mi imbatto in questa espressione e non so se l'aggiunta di questo "no" ha l'effetto di rafforzare la negazione espressa da "nient'affatto" o "certamente no" oppure serve a dare l'idea del contrario. O magari il significato è diverso o leggermente diverso.

Si tratta di un'espressione comune o il suo uso è ristretto a qualche ambito (magari regionale)? È un'espressione colloquiale?

Per cercare di capire se si tratta di un'espressione più o meno diffusa, ho ricercato "quando mai no" su Google. Ho trovato, in effetti, qualche occorrenza (e, per questa ragione, mi piacerebbe comprenderne il significato: non mi sembra un'invenzione dell'autore, ma qualcosa che si usa, non so se molto o poco e non so se in tutta Italia).
Ecco un esempio tratto dal [blog di Luciano Odorisio](https://lucianoodorisio.it/da-quando-onesta-e-coglioneria-sono-sinonimi-di-antonio-valenzi/) (grassetto mio):

> Il caso del giorno – e **quando mai no**! – è il M5S.

Questo esempio sembra essere compatibile con l'ipotesi che il significato sia "come no", ma non sono sicura che il senso sia questo.

Il problema è che appaiono anche molte false occorrenze. Per esempio, questo mi appare molte volte:  "Dimmi, Cupido, e quando mai​: No. 1". E anche cose di questo tipo: "Ma quando mai? No, è la signora [...]". La ricerca in sequenza sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, però, non produce nessun risultato. Non so se da questo fatto si possa dedurre che sia  un'espressione molto poco usata o forse si tratti di qualche sorta di neologismo. (Curiosamente questo romanzo di La Capria è nell'elenco di opere citate dal GDLI, cosa che mi va benissimo per trovare il significato di altri termini che appaiono nel libro.)

Comment: Secondo me è equivalente a "certo, come no"

Comment: "Quando mai" significa enfaticamente "no". "Quando mai no" significa "siamo alle solite", "succedesse una volta qualche cosa di diverso".

Comment: Va bene, grazie dei vostri commenti, ma qualcuno potrebbe scrivere una risposta, per favore?

Comment: @Charo L'espressione ha un significato piuttosto retorico volendo invitare qualcuno a negare qualcosa di piuttosto evidente: difatti, a rigore, dovrebbe dirsi "quando mai non è così!".